# Getting Error message "failure sending mail " while Sendmail using localhaost in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to send mail from machine(Windows 7), which doesn't have IIS server and mail server but this machine is connected to LAN. Do we really need IIS server to send mail with localhost. Please help me to understand the concept of localhost, What are the pre-conditions are required to use "localhost" as SMTP server.
I tried with Gmail SMTP host, it was working fine without any issues.

Here is my Code :

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();               
client.Host = "localhost";                
client.Port = 25;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Admin", "password");
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;              
try
{
client.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
logger.LogInfo(ex.Message); 
}
```

Thanks,
Delwin

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use IIS/ mail server / something for sending from your local machine.

If you are just trying to test, then you can use this to help simulate it:

http://antix.co.uk/Projects/SMTP-Server-For-Developers

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Smtp4Dev](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) if you want just to do some testing during development.

If I remember well SMTP was stripped from the latest versions of IIS, so you'll need to find another tool anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To send an email you need an SMTP server program. You either have one locally (i.e. "localhost", and handily for you there is one built into IIS), or you connect to a remote server.

If you don't like the idea of IIS I'm sure there are other SMTP servers you could use, but you'll need something if you wish to send locally.

Comment: Thanks Pete.. can you share the details about SMTP servers Which I can use for sending mails.

Comment: no personal experience since I've always used iis. However top of the pops on google brings you back to this site... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076/need-a-lightweight-free-windows-smtp-server

Answer (score 0):

You don't need smtp server, you can store mails in filesystem, set your development web.config like this :

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
      <specifiedPickupDirectory
            pickupDirectoryLocation="w:\razvoj\TestAndBuild\UnitTestMailSend" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```